# .NET HTTPReguest GetResponse() get first N bytes

Tags: c#, .net, http, httprequest

I'm trying to create a website crawler. it's going to retrieve some data from  many websites.
some times if I load just 1000 first bytes of a webpage, I can see what I am looking for.
here is my code:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

when I call request.GetResponse(), it will load whole the page (for example 4000 bytes) but the data that I'm looking for is in the first 1000 bytes. and when I call ReadToEnd(), it will read all the received data from RAM. but whole the data sent to my computer from the website! I don't want to receive all bytes, I need only N bytes of the first.
If I can do it so I save many many internet traffic.
can you help me? how can I do that?

Comment: Don't call `ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: @timothyclifford , I know does StreamReader object works, but the bigest problem is when I call Request.getResponse() it will get all the byte from website and keep a copy of data on the RAM. When you can .ReadToEnd() or .ReadBytes() functions it will read all the data from RAM!! I want to prevent extra bytes to be downloaded into the RAM! the Problem Is "How to get ONLY first 1000 bytes from a WEBSITE" thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [StreamReader.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.100).aspx), eg.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
char[] c = new char[1000]; // 1000 bytes
sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length); 
string responseString  = new string(c);
```

Comment: I think when I Resquest.GetStream(), it will download all the bytes to the RAM. and when I response.GetResponseStream() it will read bytes from the RAM. is it right?